# Textpad 7 - how to turn off tabbed document interface?

Tags: text-editors, textpad

I have been using TextPad for 10 years, various versions, and I've always had it configured so the document windows are movable within the frame. If I opened up 10 files at a time, their windows would come up staggered, on top of each other. I could rearrange them so I could have several side by side, and have windows of varying widths if I needed.

I just had to reinstall because my work machine was reimaged, and I got TextPad 7.5.1 (64-bit). I can't find how to get it not to do a tabbed interface.

Answer (score 0):

1. From the **View** menu, uncheck **Document Tabs**
2. Click the **Restore Window** button in the top-right corner of TextPad

This produces the result you want:

[image]